# Compare shipping prices from online calculatorso

Tags: javascript, php, web

I need to compare shipping prices from calculators on various parcel delivery websites, using one calculator form on my shipping price comparison website.
Problem is, there is no API or data feed on every parcel shipping website that I want to compare. Any suggestion for problem solution?

Comment: you could curl/file_get_contents and the crop the result you're looking for

Comment: Without API, You need to crawl those shipping website's pricing page and parse the shipping price.

Comment: I know that I need to crawl, but I it possible to crawl online calculator?